# How to achieve "max_should_match" type of query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-6

If I have multiple match clauses in my query, how do I achieve a behaviour where the second (or subsequent) clause is run only if previous clauses have returned no matches. i.e., something like `max_should_match`.

In my use case, I have two clauses similar to this,

```
[
  {
    <Normal Match query>
  },
  {
    <Fuzzy Match query>
  }
]
```

I do not want fuzzy results, unless and until I get NO results with the normal match query.

Elasticsearch version - 6.3